# rawlog_mrpt_to_bagfile

Tags: laser, rosbag, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I need 2d laser data of horizontal terrain, but I am unable in getting that, so I am using data from (mrpt.org), rawlog format but can any please tell me how to convert the rawlog file in to bag or input data.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10218/rawlog_mrpt_to_bagfile/) by [ravi](https://answers.ros.org/users/624/ravi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-06-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-06-09**:
Could you also tell what kind of data you are searching after? Perhaps some users have this laying around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are conversions between ROS data types and some mrpt data types in the [mrpt-ros-pkg repo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/mrpt-ros-pkg)

The documentation is quite spares, but I do remember seeing conversion methods which you could use in a custom program.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0